# Change Swagger UI `server` dynamically at run time based on the url it is running on

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I am using a `swagger` interface to test my API endpoints. I Have this running on two different servers

1. A production server `https://example.co.app`
2. A staging server  `https://example-staging.co.app`

I managed to make a dropdown list to select the server you want to use like so in a via `options` in a `config.js` file:

```
servers: [
{
      url: 'https://example.co.app',
      description: 'prod server'
    },
    {
      url: 'https://example-staging.co.app',
      description: 'staging server'
    }
]
```

This works but will always use `prod server` by default since it is the first one in the list.

I would like to make the default dynamic at run time based on what server It is actually running in.

Is this possible with swagger configurations?

Comment: Would a relative URL work in your scenario - `url: '/'`? Or do you still need an ability to choose the server manually (e.g. open Swagger UI on Staging but then select the Prod server)?

Comment: @Helen no there is no need for the manual selection. would `/` automatically assign the the URL accessed?